# Particular Monad. Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have written a my monad representing some computations. Now, I would like to define how the computation should be `sequenced`. So, I am going to define `>>=` . But, control of flow forced me to focus on conrete type of `a`. I mean:

```
m >>= f = 
     a <- m 
     case a of
        (ParticularParameterA) -> doSomething
          ..........
```

Is it proper solution? I mean: I have no experience in functional programming so I am not sure is it ok to do it or not. How to do it better?

Comment: `m` should already have a fixed type, by your monad instance, so there should be no switching needed nor possible. Do you mean that you are selecting/switching on the constructor of your monad type?

Comment: Yes, Indeed it has. I edited.

Comment: Your edit just made the code nonsensical, having a `<-` outside of a do-block / list comprehension.

Comment: Not considering the edit, without seeing more of your code it's quite impossible to tell if it's OK or not. Maybe you could think on the exact question and the relevant details you need to show us to judge this case, and then update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that your situation falls into the simple pattern where your monad if of the form:

```
newtype MyMonad a = MyMonad { run :: State -> (a, State) }
```

where `State` is a data type you have designed yourself. The point is you probably have a function:

```
run :: MyMonad a -> State -> (a, State)
```

and you probably need to use this function when implementing (>>=):

```
m >>= f = MyMonad(\state -> let (x, newState) = run m state in
                              case x of 
                                (ParticularParameterA) -> doSomething
                                 ..........
```

Now if `f::a -> MyMonad b` your `\state -> ...` function must return a `(b, State)`, so you probably want to use `run (f x) newState` somewhere in your code.

if your monadic type is of the form:

```
newtype MyMonad a = MyMonad { run :: State -> Maybe (a, State) }
newtype MyMonad a = MyMonad { run :: State -> Either String  (a, State) }
```

then you still use the `run` function, e.g.

```
m >>= f = MyMonad (\state -> case run m state of
                               Just (x, newState) -> run (f x) newState
                               Nothing               -> Nothing)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `case` statement and syntax errors notwithstanding, this definition is indeed clearly nonsensical, as binding from within a do-block gets translated to a use of `>>=`. So your existing code has defined `m >>= f = m >>= \a -> ...`, which is both an infinite loop and a space leak in one.